# Excel-Table named like Worksheet-Function overwrites it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges, excel-tables

I have a table in my Excel-Workbook named "Year".

Using the formula `=YEAR(A1)`  returns an reference error. Excel thinks I want to reference the table "Year" instead of the function. The table overwrites the built-in function `YEAR` .

Does somebody know how to "tell" Excel that my Formula wants to reference the function and not the table?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Asking the obvious, but why can't you rename the table?

Comment: @BigBen The table sits within a workbook with many different use cases and I am simply not sure if renaming the table destroys some behaviour somewhere else.

Comment: I highly doubt it.

Comment: @BigBen Well probably. If I would have to guess I also would think it wont destroy anything. I thought maybe somebody has a solution for it though. But maybe I just have to do it and hope it doesnt cause too bad errors (if any)

Comment: Solution: don't shadow inbuilt function names.

Comment: If you rename the table, all the references will update to the new table name, unless you've got some referenced in a closed workbook. You can always just name it to "YearTbl"

Comment: @Kairu okay yeah the workbook totally stands on it’s own. That resolves my fear that it could cause any errors! Thank you for pointing that out